# ReactJS: handleClick syntax

Tags: reactjs

Just starting out with ReactJS, and I'm stumped about syntax. The code below works, but I'm not sure why. This produces a function that tells you if you're logged in or not in a , then logs you in or out (changes state) when you click the button.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
            }
        })
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoggedIn ? <h1>You are now logged in.</h1> : <h1>You are now logged out.</h1>}
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.isLoggedIn ? <h3>LOG OUT</h3> : <h3>LOG IN</h3>}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

- `handleClick` function: what's `prevState`? I'm stumped by this because it was never initialized as a var or let or anything like that.
- I believe that the `onClick` prop is supposed to accept a function (that is `handleClick()`). But the way that `handleClick()` is written looks like it returns a new state? So `{this.handleClick}` would return the updated state?

Comment: Ask one question per question. You have asked two completely different questions and this should really be two stack questions. I recommend changing the question title to reflect your first question to help other people who have the same problem discover this thread. I have answered your first question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's prevState?

That's the state before `handleClick` function was called. `setState` function is used to change the state of the react component. This `setState` function can accept a function that receives the current state as an argument which is then modified in the function body. To completely understand how you should modify the state of your component and how `setState` function works, see [using state correctly in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

> So {this.handleClick} would return the updated state?

No. It will call the `handleClick` function when button is clicked. See [handling events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for better understanding of how this works in react

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
        }
    })
}
```

could just be rewritten as

```
handleClick() {
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn})
    }
```

`setState` can either be a function or you can pass it an object. I recommend passing it an object if you are starting out because it just simpler to think about. The reason people also use an updater function is because it references the previous state, the state before it is changed, and this can be useful for batched changes.

For example, let's say you increment a count in state using a state update function 3 times then the final count will be 3.

```
state = {count: 0}

this.setState( previousState => ({count: previousState.count++}))
this.setState( previousState => ({count: previousState.count++}))
this.setState( previousState => ({count: previousState.count++}))

this.state.count = 3
```

If you increment state 3 times just using a regular object then the changes will get batched together. Something that often gets overlooked is that setState is asynchronous. State may not change immediately on calling setState because react batches state changes for performance.

```
state = {count: 0}

this.setState( { count: this.state.count++})
this.setState( { count: this.state.count++})
this.setState( { count: this.state.count++})

this.state.count = 1
```

So, if you need to reference current state then use an updater function, if you don’t then you can just use an object.

Comment: your function in onClick question is a completely different question and i think you should split these two questions out into separate stack questions. To answer the question though, the react doc is always a good place to start before you come to stack for general explanations of [how things work](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and here are [5 ways to bind functions](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) to help you understand what is going on.